# get Well Known Text from lat long

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, postgis, geodjango, wkt

I can get easily a lat,long pair from the Google Maps API:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
gmaps = GoogleMaps(GOOGLEMAPS_API_KEY)
gmaps.address_to_latlng('Jose Javier Diaz 440 Cordoba Argentina')
>>>> (-31.4464489, -64.191219899999993)
```

And I have a model like this:

```
from django import models
class MaapPoint(models.Model):
   geom = models.PointField(srid=DEFAULT_SRID)
```

But I can't find a way to get the `wkt` from the `latlng` returned by `gmaps`. 
Any pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In django, `contrib.gis` has helpers for this.

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> Point(0,1).wkt
'POINT (0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000)'
```

Answer (score 3):

[Shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) provides a nice API for that:

```
>>> import shapely
>>> from shapely.wkt import dumps, loads
>>> pt1 = loads('POINT (0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000)')
>>> pt1
<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x1011436d0>
>>> dumps(pt1)
'POINT (0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000)'
>>> pt3 = shapely.geometry.point.Point(2, 3)
>>> dumps(pt3)
'POINT (2.0000000000000000 3.0000000000000000)'
```